# View in scrollview gets hidden when requestFocus() is called

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` where there are a number of `EditText` fields.

When i call `requestFocus()` on any of those fields, the `EditText` fields comes into view as the scroll view scrolls by itself, even when the soft keyboard is up.

The problem lies in the fact that i have had to add a separate view above the soft keyboard to accommodate a clear button, and it is that custom view that is hiding the edit text field in focus.

Now, i have to manually scroll the scroll view to see the edit text field in focus.

Please help me to show the edit text field in focus above the custom view which is placed on top of the soft keyboard.

**Is there any way to do so ?**

EDIT:: This is how i solved this problem.

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                        scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom()-200);
                    } 
            });
```

and gradually went on decreasing the amount i am subtracting from the scrollView.getBottom() call. This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your `manifest.xml` file, for your activity just add this line:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: This did not really work for me. What did was        scrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
             scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom()-200);
            } 
    });                                         and gradually went on decreasing the amount i am subtracting from the scrollView.getBottom() call. This worked fine for me. Thanks for the reply though.